# Validate function and return variables to input()

Tags: python, validation, input

I made a function that validates 2 variables provided by user in input. 
I have two problems:

1. In the function `break` giving me and error: `break` outside loop. I can not fix it.
2. If input is sent to function and when it fails, how can I send it back to input for user to re-enter?

Please find below code:

```
def testify(arg_test):
    while True:
        i =  arg_test
    try:
        i == int(i)
    except ValueError as e:
      print ("Enter valid int value")
    else:   
         break
    return arg_test

number_1 = input("Write first number: ");
number_2 = input("Write second number: ");

arg_number_1 = testify(number_1);
arg_number_2 = testify(number_2);
```

Comment: You have indentation issues, In python indentation is very important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indentation issues in your code, please take a look to this fix:

```py
def testify(arg_test):
    i =  arg_test
    try:
        int(i) # This is sufficient to test if arg_test could be parsed as an integer
        return arg_test
    except ValueError as e:
        new_input = input("Enter valid int value")
        return testify(new_input)
```

**Edit:**
Changed my answer to use a recursive function that checks new inputs from  the user.

Comment: in except statement you can make it a reccursive function to solve back problem 2

Comment: With this change it uses a recursive function, if the input is valid, then it returns the original argument, otherwise, it will enter again into the function and therefore the loop is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

First, the question I'm most sure about: 2) re-enter variable after your `try except` error.

I would just do the following code:

```
else:
    break()
    testify(arg_test)
```

The 1st question I am not so sure about, the `break` function as it is rarely used by me! But I would say: **try indenting your `try` and `except` loop so it is underneath the `while True:` loop!**

Like this:

```
def testify(arg_test):
    while True:
        i =  arg_test
        try:
            i == int(i)
        except ValueError as e:
            print ("Enter valid int value")
        else:   
            break
            testify(arg_test)
    return arg_test
```

Hope this helps!